# Where to find my discourse output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, discourse

I am new to discourse. It all working fine but I didn't get the output at the desired port 127.0.0.1 that i used ass discourse_hostname but  I see nothing in my browser
[image: error discourse]

Answer (score 0):

```
Graham@docker:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS                                                             
NAMES
3f8ac711da37        local_discourse/app   "/sbin/boot"        23 hours ago        
Up 23 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:300-
>3000/tcp   app
```

will let you know the various ports it's listening at.